# onbeforeunload event processing problems on Windows 10 in Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I'm using `onbeforeunload` event handler to trigger browser dialog "Do you really want to exit" in case user did some data entry.

Up till lately it worked without problems, but lately browsers (latest version of Chrome and Edge, Windows 10) gets in a strange loop before asking the question. It moves browser window several times, each time a bit to the left and up, until it reaches upper left corner. Only then it asks the question. There is no such problem in Firefox.

This is my simple test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="1" type="radio" onchange="change()">
  <label for="1">Test</label>
<script>
  var changed = false;
  
  function change() {
    changed = true;
  }
  
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    if (changed) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.returnValue = true;
    }
  };
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is how browser looks during this strange moving process:

[image]

Is this a bug or there was some change in how this event should be processed in Chrome an Edge?

Comment: Stack Overflow asks if you want leave the site if your mid way asking / replying to a question, I'm not getting that effect.  I'm on Linux / Chrome 121.0.6167.139.  If you do the same, does SO work OK, or is it just this site your creating?.  Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. I see the same problem on StackExchange site if I start asking question and then try to close browser

Comment: In that case I would say 1: There is a bug with the Windows 10 version   2: You have some 3rd party software that you recently installed not playing well.   eg. Have you maybe installed some screen capture utility, or some fancy window manager,  etc.

Comment: No fancy stuff installed lately. I remembered now that I have some old Windows 7 in VM. I'll try how it goes there.

Comment: Checked in venerable old Windows 7, no problems for Edge, Chrome or Firefox. Created Windows 11 VM, no problems for Edge or Chrome.

Comment: What happens if you use it via an eventListener, like so: `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() { ... });`? Or, if you test your code in incognito mode (preferably with extensions and add-ons disabled, if you have any)? Or, if you test your code on another Windows 10 device (either a physical one, or another VM, this time with Windows 10 installed)?

Comment: `window.addEventListener("beforeunload" ...` does not help. Incognito mode does not help. I have one extension in Edge and different one in Chrome, so that can't be the reason. I'll try to get hold of Windows 10 install.